# How to rename a QGIS plugin?

Tags: qgis, python

I updated a plugin such that now it does more operations than the original title suggests.  Is there an easy way to change the name without going through all of the files line by line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `C:\Users\<username>\.qgis2\python\plugins\`, just rename the folder of the plugin. It will appear in the plugin list with that name. Once renamed, it can not be overwritten from the plugin repository. You have to activate it manually in the `installed` list to get it running.

Furthermore, you can change name and version number in the `metadata.txt` file.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't make it work, could you elaborate more on it? I changed folder name and every piece of metadata.txt. Now proper name displays only as a header of dialog box (that one I changed in QtDesigner) as well as in a Plugins Manager with correct metadata. But in Plugins menu it doesn't, neither when I hover mouse on the plugin button on the toolbar.

Comment: I also did the `grep -r ...` command inside the plugin folder, but it returned nothing.

Comment: The menu entry is defined in the python code of the plugin, most probably after `def initGui(self)` in `<pluginname>.py`. It might help to delete the .pyc file after editing the file.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, @AndreJ describes creating a local copy of a plugin, and renaming it. What you cannot do is rename a plugin on the QGIS plugins repository website, even if you are that plugin's author. If you change the name of a plugin you maintain yourself, it will become a new plugin in the repository. Old versions and download stats from the previously named plugin will not carry across to the renamed one.